# Desktop application options related to Java

Tags: java, desktop-application

These days I got an offer related to a desktop application that I should create.

I'm a `Java` programmer. I had worked with `Swing` API about 4 years ago, so I can say that I have some experience with it. I also had worked with `Flex 4` about one year ago, but I think it is not a good option for what I need. In my opinion it is not stable enough (present some strange behavior) and I think it is no longer maintained for `Linux` platform. - (if you think I'm wrong here, tell me).

So, I search for a good Desktop UI API that I should use with `Java`.

What are the actual desktop UI "trends", taking in account that questions on that issue are relatively old on SO?

N.B. When it comes to talk about platform independence and `SWT`, I think there are some issues. That's why I would not opt for it.

Comment: @Kev *Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development* - I think my question can be fitted in the "software development" category. Even if it isn't about writing code. Probably I have a misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally use JavaFX for any new UI development work in Java - it's now a 100% Java API and [Oracle appear to be pushing it quite strongly](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/roadmap-1446331.html):

> JavaFX has become more tightly integrated with Java SE, and will soon become a standard component of the platform. Starting with JavaFX 2.0.2 / Java SE 7u2, the JavaFX SDK has become part of the Java SE 7 JDK, avoiding a separate download for developers. The next step in this integration is to include the JavaFX runtime libraries as part of the JRE, which will be achieved through the Java SE 7u6 / JavaFX 2.2 releases in summer 2012. This will ensure widespread adoption of JavaFX on Java-enabled computers, while leveraging  synchronized updates and security fixes.

Having used it myself, in my opinion it's also far nicer than Swing in its API (more like SWT in that respect), looks far nicer by default, and far more flexible in what it allows you to do.